# How to get ./configure to generate defaults

Tags: git, autoconf

In attempting to compile git under qnx, I’ve found it difficult to cleanly compile after running ./configure.  I can get a much better result using the majority of the defaults.

What I’d like to find out is what the differences are between make without configure and make with configure so I can find out where configure is going wrong.

The output in configure.log hasn’t been much help so I was wondering if there is a way to generate the configure outputs without actually performing the configure process.  Something that will spit out all the defaults that would be used if configure wasn’t run in the first place.  I could then compare the two to find out what might be the problem.

Does anything like that exist?

Thanks, 
xl600

Comment: I muddled through my QNX build issues, but am still wondering if configure can be made to output all defaults.  My solution for QNX 6.3.0 and git 2.4.5 (With curl installed) is in the next post.

Comment: Modify files:

pager.c must be modified for QNX's limited command line args as follows:
 
     if (!getenv("LESS"))
        /* QNX less does not support FRX, just rX */
        argv_array_push(&pager_process.env_array, "LESS=rX");

In perl/Makefile.PL, modify the PM_FILTER line to read (Replaces <> with {} due to the use of perl <5.10, also removes "++LOCALDIR++" since that isn't compatible with older perl interpreters):

PM_FILTER   => qq[\$(PERL) -pe "s{\\QXXLOCALEDIRXX\\E}{$localedir}"],

In perl/Git/I18N.pm

our $TEXTDOMAINDIR = $ENV{GIT_TEXTDOMAINDIR} || 'XXLOCALEDIRXX';

Comment: Configure:

./configure CC=/usr/qnx630/host/qnx6/x86/usr/bin/cc CFLAGS='-Wall' --without-iconv --disable-pthreads --disable-gettext --with-pager=/usr/bin/less
 
Build:

make prefix=/usr PERL_PATH=/usr/bin/perl PYTHON_PATH=/opt/bin/python CURLDIR=/usr/local NO_DEFLATE_BOUND=1 NO_TCLTK=1 OPENSSLDIR=/usr